# Formatting decimal output when multiplying all numerical values in a string?

Tags: formatting, numbers, decimal, preg-replace, string-formatting

I have this case where I have to multiply the numbers of a string but some of the values are in EUR and some are percentage. I made it this far as code goes:

```
    $string = "description: test1: 10 €, test2: 7.50 €, test3: 25%, test4: 30%";
    $levelamt = 0.75;

$description = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]+)\s*(\s€|%)/i', function($matches) use ($levelamt){
   return ($matches[1] * $levelamt).$matches[2];
}, $string);

echo $description;
```

But it outputs this:

> description: test1: 7.5 €, test2: 7.37.5 €, test3: 18.75%, test4:
>   22.5%

How should I modify the regular expression to multiply decimals and round the results of numbers? I want output to be like so:

> description: test1: 7.**50** €, test2: 5.**63** €, test3: 18.75%,
>   test4: 22.**5**%

So when it is € value to format it XX.YY € and when it is percentage value to format it XX.YY% when percentage is a hundreds and XX.Y% when percentage decimal is a tenth. I tried rounding. Maybe I do not put it in the right place. I also tried replacing **[0-9]** part of the regex to find only decimals but this brings in other problems. A bit stuck here. Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `$description = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9][.0-9]*)\s*(\s€|%)/i', function($matches) use ($levelamt){
   return round(($matches[1] * $levelamt),2).$matches[2];
}, $string);`? See https://3v4l.org/H4WY9

Comment: The regex might also be `'/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/'`

Comment: Note that `7.50 €` and `22.5%` is not consistent, I understand you want to have 2 digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. Well, looks like I will display % with 2 decas everywhere else, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$string = "description: test1: 10 €, test2: 7.50 €, test3: 25%, test4: 30%";
$levelamt = 0.75;

$description = preg_replace_callback('/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\s*[€%])/i', function($matches) use ($levelamt){
   return number_format(round(($matches[1] * $levelamt), 2), 2).$matches[2];
}, $string);

echo $description;
// => description: test1: 7.50 €, test2: 5.63 €, test3: 18.75%, test4: 22.50%
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/kIrUH)

The regex will match

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` followed with 1+ digits
- `(\s*[€%])` - Group 2: 0+ whitespaces followed with `€` or `%`.

The `round` function will round the result of the multiplication and `number_format` will format the number as you need, with 2 digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you! Upped!